# How to remove this file with special characters

Tags: bash, rm

The file I'm trying to remove contains special characters in file name. This is how the file looks from vim editor (if I open the directory through vi) -

```
<200c>minaldi.pdf
```

I tried all possible way I knew for file removal e.g. find with "inum", using escape sequence but nothing seems to help.

I tried -

```
find . -type f -inum 37700 -exec rm '{}' \;
rm: cannot remove `./‌minaldi.pdf': No such file or directory
```

Here 37700 is the inum for the file.

Here's the file name using **ls | cat -v** command -

```
M-bM-^@M-^Lminaldi.pdf
```

and using **ls | od -bc** command -

```
0000000 342 200 214 155 151 156 141 154 144 151 056 160 144 146 012
        342 200 214   m   i   n   a   l   d   i   .   p   d   f  \n
0000017
```

Comment: Have you tried `rm -f *minaldi.pdf`?

Comment: Andrew, tried `rm -f *minaldi.pdf`. Doesn't remove the file.

Comment: @jm666, tried perl cmd -

`> perl -E 'unlink("\N{ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER}minaldi.pdf")'

Constant(\N{ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER}minaldi.pdf): $^H{charnames} is not defined at -e line 1, within string

Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.`

Comment: @jm666 perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi

Comment: @jm666 sure will try with newer perl. btw the other command also didn't work -
`perl -Mcharnames=:full -E 'unlink("\N{ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER}minaldi.pdf")'`

Comment: (almost) all of the suggestions should have worked. `No such file or directory` is an indication of a deeper problem - something is wrong with the kernel or the filesystem or the mount options. Anyway, this question is better suited for [unix.se] or [su].

Comment: Try to delete the whole directory! (After having moved away the files you want to keep...)

Comment: @linuxfan can't remove the dir as the file is not removed somehow -
`> rm -fr mydir
rm: cannot remove ``mydir': Directory not empty`

Comment: fsck, then fsdb, debugfs or similar...

Comment: @jm666 tried the command with perl v5.26.1. It doesn't err out but doesn't remove the file either :(

`perl -Mcharnames=:full -E 'unlink("\N{ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER}minaldi.pdf")'`

Comment: @NEO - if the perl doesn't removed it, then Roman is correct and the problem is deeper as shell - so here is some problem with the underlaying OS. Im going to remove all my comments above (to clean up) :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use find's internal delete parameter:

```
find . -type f -inum 37700 -delete
```

Comment: `> find . -type f -inum 37700 -delete
find: cannot delete ``./‌minaldi.pdf': No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

Use `echo` to escape that:

```
rm "$(echo -en './‌\xE2\x80\x8Cminaldi.pdf')"
```

Comment: I get this error -

`rm: cannot remove ``./‌\\xE2\\x80\\x8Cminaldi.pdf': No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

If it's only for a one time remove and not for use in a script, use `-i` for interactive. Specify as much as you can for the file name, so that you don't have to go through too many file names:

```
rm -i *minaldi.pdf
```

This will ask for each file matching the pattern whether you want to delete it.

Comment: Tried that already :(

`> rm -i *minaldi.pdf
rm: remove regular file ``‌minaldi.pdf'? y
rm: cannot remove ``minaldi.pdf': No such file or directory`